# Is PhpMyAdmin able to handle large amount of data?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

And when I mean "large" its only `~25000 rows` ...

I have a large table that weight `5 Mb` and when trying to list all the data and review the information, PhpMyAdmin displays the following error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 29050028 bytes) in
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/phpmyadmin/libraries/DisplayResults.class.php
>   on line 2561

It's only `25K` rows, what will it be when it will be over `100K` ?

I've look online on how to fix it and I've raised the resources limit in `PHP.ini` to:

> ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; ; Resource Limits ; ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
>
> ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds ;
>   http://php.net/max-execution-time ; Note: This directive is hardcoded
>   to 0 for the CLI SAPI max_execution_time = 1000
>
> ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data.
>   It's a good ; idea to limit this time on productions servers in order
>   to eliminate unexpectedly ; long running scripts. ; Note: This
>   directive is hardcoded to -1 for the CLI SAPI ; Default Value: -1
>   (Unlimited) ; Development Value: 60 (60 seconds) ; Production Value:
>   60 (60 seconds) ; http://php.net/max-input-time max_input_time = 1000
>
> ; Maximum input variable nesting level ;
>   http://php.net/max-input-nesting-level ;max_input_nesting_level = 64
>
> ; How many GET/POST/COOKIE input variables may be accepted
>   max_input_vars = 10000
>
> ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB) ;
>   http://php.net/memory-limit memory_limit = 128M

But nothing changed.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: you're a human, phpmyadmin is intended for human interaction. How are you going to meaningfully interpret 25000 rows of data? If you're using phpmyadmin to do automation, you actually want to write scripts that interface with your database, not use phpmyadmin.

Comment: that's where pagination comes in I'm only trying to display results 10 by 10

Comment: Did you restart your web server after making changes to your php.ini

Comment: but you're still a human, and you're not going to meaningfully understand 25000 rows in pages of 10. So either you're overloading "paging" to do something that you should adjust your query for (ie find the set of highest/lowest/whatever) or you should be writing scripts that simply access your db. phhmyadmin is not a substitute for actually using your database properly, it's just for administration.

Comment: yes I did, and I've restarted mysql as well

Comment: All right so you mean phpmyadmin is no use anymore after a few thousands of rows and I should exclusively use my own admin panel ?

Comment: The database still shouldn't choke returning all the rows.

Comment: no, I mean it's an administration panel, not a data manipulation tool. If you're running operations that operate on even 1000 rows, you've crossed the line from administration to just "using your database".

Comment: interesting .. all right thanks, I'm gonna exclusively use my own admin panel from now on I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error you are getting

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 29050028 bytes) in /Library/WebServer/Documents/phpmyadmin/libraries/DisplayResults.class.php on line 2561
```

Means your script surpassed the 128M memory limit that's already set. Therefore, any meaningful increase in php.ini should be above 128M. 256M should be your next step. Remember to restart apache or your fastcgi service after doing that.

PHPMyAdmin is able to handle unlimited amount of data when it comes to exporting a table to sql, csv or spreadsheets. It just cannot handle that much data when it comes to display a nice interactive grid with ajax updates and gritty buttons. That's because the table's content is injected into an object, and that object must hold the whole content in memory until it renders.

If 10000 rows amount for more than 128M, then PHP cannot hold that info in a variable. That's not PHPMyadmin's fault.

Comment: thanks, why is it trying to hold the whole table when I just want to display it page per page (say 25 results per page).

Comment: in that case, it shouldn't. It only needs to hold 25 rows at any given time. This means the problem is somewhere else, and it could be a bug in a given PHPMyAdmin version. They are releasing new hotfixes almost twice a month, so let's not discard that. I'd try increasing the memory limit to 256MB or even 512MB instead of debugging a third party tool.